# SystemJS: Named AMD modules sometimes have empty defaults

Tags: amd, systemjs

This is based on [this functional demo](https://codepen.io/tnunamak/pen/GXRvZG?editors=0012).

I'm seeing that unnamed modules are imported by SystemJS 0.21.4 as empty objects.

```
// define('a', [], function () { return 'A'; });
SystemJS.import('a.js')
  .then(m => console.log(m.default, '<- a')) // "A"

// define('b', [], function () { return 'B'; });
SystemJS.import('b.js')
  .then(m => console.log(m.default, '<- b')) // {}

// define([], function () { return 'A'; });
SystemJS.import('a-anon.js')
  .then(m => console.log(m.default, '<- a-anon'))  // "A"

// define([], function () { return 'B'; });
SystemJS.import('b-anon.js')
  .then(m => console.log(m.default, '<- b-anon')) // "B"
```

For some reason, `a.js` imports correctly as "A", but `b.js` imports as an empty object (instead of "B"). If I reorder them so that `b.js` is imported first, I see the opposite--b imports correctly and a does not.

What's going on here? Is this a bug? Am I using SystemJS/AMD incorrectly?

<sub>Cross-posted [from Github](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1837)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the first argument, the "id", which must be top-level:

> The first argument, id, is a string literal. It specifies the id of the module being defined. This argument is optional, and if it is not present, the module id should default to the id of the module that the loader was requesting for the given response script. When present, the module id MUST be a "top-level" or absolute id (relative ids are not allowed).

[More details on the AMD-page on github.](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD#id-)

In the case of `B` just the object of the module is returned. Module here is the function in which the definition is made.

There are still one interesting point, even it might not be too surprising:
If the 2nd URL is loaded first (b.js) even if the sorting in the script is a.js, b.js, then `B` is also the assigned Symbol. That means the first transferred definition-file wins. You can test it by loading one file from cdn, the other one local.

Furthermore, if you assign C and D in the same kind like A and B, then also the objects get shown. So the behavior is the same like with B.

Like you've shown with your two last examples the problem never occurs, when the id as optional parameter is omitted.

Comment: Thank you David. I'm trying to understand how your explanation applies to my example. Are you saying that the ids "a" and "b" are not top-level/absolute? They do not start with "." or "..", so they seem top-level to me.

What is the relationship between "the object of the module" and the loading order? And when you say "B" is the assigned Symbol when b.js loads first, what is this Symbol and what is its significance?

Comment: You can load only one definition with id, all other id's will be ignored.
To assure that the right one is loaded with id you should only use one assignment of id (with respect to any unpredictable changes in loading-order). In your example a and b are intended being both top-level, but only one is allowed.
The example is no real use-case so it's only a nice presentation/testcase about the definitions in AMD. With the function you defined in `a` you have the possibility to assign an id dynamically to the module, that seems being the sense of that construction for me and other need not given.

Comment: Okay, my understanding of AMD is definitely off. I thought vendor libraries like React would call `define('react', ...` as a mechanism for other modules to `require('react')`, but this does not seem to be what they do, and it does not seem to be the purpose of the ID at all. I'm still not sure I understand why I can load even a single definition with an ID, but this is certainly starting to make more sense. Thanks.

Comment: As long as only one id per module is loaded your use-case with react is not wrong and doesn't collide with my description.